# Lambda triggers for DynamoDB changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm planning on changing my service from using SQS as temporary storage that trigger lambdas to process the data to using DynamoDB for more permanent storage.

DynamoDB offers a trigger for each row change which can also be batched together which is great. But it will also trigger on Deletes, which is something that I do not want as that could trigger 1000 lambdas which nothing to do. 
Is there a way to disable triggering on Deletes and only listen to Insert and Modify?

Another approach that I’ve been thinking about is to have another lambda query the database for new changes and then launch lambdas based on the changed input. For this approach I'm a bit unsure what the best way to trigger the lambdas are to get more concurrent executions, I'm afraid that if i trigger the lambdas for each change that I would hit the lambda execution ceiling.

Pushing it to SQS and having that trigger the lambda should work, but is there a way to do this without sqs?

Comment: I guess a simpler question is do I have to keep track of the number of executions with a queue or can I just trigger as many lambdas as I need and AWS would queue these up for me

Comment: There are limits on how many lambda functions can execute at the same time. By default it is 1000 per account per region. But yes, AWS will scale it up to your limits if needed.

Comment: @Marcin What i'm worried about is that IF i would hit any limit it would start failing and the failed jobs would not get picked up. 
Maybe it's better if I keep my SQS queue as JobQueue that handles retries for me

Comment: If the SQS is working fine there is maybe no need to change it by force. And you still can keep messages/events of interest in DynamoDB, by having your lambdas which process the SQS also write to dynamodb.

Comment: Yes, that is my conclusion as well. I'll will go with that, store the data in both Dynamo and use SQS as lambda job queues which has worked in the past. 
Thanks